# Different between socks4 and http-s proxy in instagram BOT

Tags: php, curl, bots, reverse-engineering, php-curl

I want to know what is the different between `socks4` proxy and `http/https` proxy while using Instagram BOT sites. I am using `socks4` proxy for my Instagram bot and after few days my users accounts start blocking to like comment or follow anyone, I want to know is that issue happen because of `socks4` proxy, If yes I want to know different between `socks4` proxy and `http/https` proxy.

Just info: http proxy return null values while hitting like etc by bot.

```
while socks4 i use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4); 
and while http i use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instagram has an algorithm in place that blocks non-human-like behavior.
This is the reason why your accounts are being blocked, not the proxy configuration.
*For example: if your bot is hitting "like" 100 times per minute.*
This is seen as a non-human behavior by the algorithm and therefore blocks the account.
Review your code and in case post some of it for us to double check. Thanks.